# How to set a dynamic url on blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm trying to implement this plugin, and i can't make it work with change dynamically the url,
Example, once i have init the plugin:

```
$('#image').fileupload({...})
```

I call the following method to set id:

```
function setUrl(id) {
    var uploadUrl = '/api/products/' + id + '/images';        
    // config upload url
    $('#image').fileupload("option", "url", uploadUrl);
}
```

but i've these error line:

```
"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Overwriting the initialization $('#image').fileupload() on the method and setting url param inside, doesn't works, its always the same url param

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could set the url in [add](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add) callback, as:

```
fileupload({
   add: function(e, data) {
      data.url = '/api/products/' + id + '/images';      
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi DemoUser, I probably making a big mistake... i've put that code inside the method setURL, that gets and id and sets the new URL. But **id** param is always the same inside data.url, before that i've checked the id and its the right one, but it seems that is keeping on fileupload config

Comment: Make sure to do a `data.submit();` inside your function, else the file won't be submitted to the server.